# jFolder::create:could not create directory in joomla 1.7

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I am getting the following error when I upload component, module in joomla 1.7

```
     jFolder::create:could not create directory
```

Please let me know how I can fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Please check CHMOD and CHOWN of parent directory.

Comment: Please give me the url there are so many nice exploits to take Joomla 1.7 down, steal all info, take control of the installation and use if for my phishing and spamming needs.  Or, maybe, update to 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when you don't have specific permissions.

You need to ensure all folders are chmod 755, in this case, you firstly need to check the folder called **tmp**.

To check which folder need to be writable and their status, login into the Joomla backend and go to:

**Site** *(top menu)* >> **System Information** >> **Directory Permissions**

On a side note, try and get your site upgraded to Joomla 2.5